# ifstream.read() of a file

Tags: c++, ifstream, ofstream

So I made an output file that does this:

```
   ofstream outf;
   outf.open(filename);
   string str = "This is test!";
   int lengthofstr = str.length();
   outf.write((char*)&str, sizeof(lengthofstr));
   outf.close();
```

After that has been completely, with another program (exe) I read in the file:

```
    void readem(char* filename, ifstream &inf){

    inf.open(filename);

        string a;

        if (inf.is_open()){
            inf.read((char*)&a, sizeof(int));
            cout << a << endl;

        }
        else
            cout << "file is not opening!" << endl;

        inf.close();
    }
```

The c++ exe breaks as soon as i try to run it. Im trying to return the string. If someone could point me to a tutorial/post/question/ or explain to me how the ifstream read works, thank you ahead of time XD

Comment: you can't just cast a `string*` to a `char*` and expect that to work

Comment: You can just do a simple `inf >> a`.

Comment: `sizeof(lengthofstr)` is the size of the variable holding the length of the string, not the actual length of the string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't write a `std::string` like this at all! The content of the file *may* contain the characters you expect it to include (because `std::string` is likely to use the small string optimization) but for bigger string it won't: the `std::string` object you are writing is just the "control record" of the actual string. To write a `std::string` you'd probably write two pieces of information:

1. The length of the `std::string` to be written.
2. The characters of the `std::string`.

The operations would look something like this:

```
write(stream, s.size());
write(stream, s.c_str(), s.size());
```

(the functions `write()` suitably implement serialization of an integer value and a sequence of characters; just writing bytes is, in my opinion, *not* the way to go)

Merely writing the characters making up a `std::string` object isn't any useful.

When reading bytes into the memory occupied by an `std::string` object you get undefined behavior: the control record part of the string gets overwritten with some content which is unlikely to yield a valid object. Assuming the object is written as above, you could read it (assuming suitable deserializing functions `read()`) using code like this:

```
std::string s;
s.resize(read<std::string::size_type>(stream));
read(stream, s.data(), s.size());
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This is what I was wondering about and I was unsure about the ifstream read and ofstream write